# Pad number with variable length zeroes using REGEX

Tags: .net, regex, formatting

I have a situation where client inputs a number, and I need to validate that number by padding a certain number of zeroes in front of it. The max length of the field that I validate is 9 digits, so if client enters '123', I need to pad it with 6 zeros in front of it and validate. Sounds easy enough, right?

Well, here is the kicker, I have no code-control over any part of the process. The only things available to me are 2 'properties' - a regex pattern and a regex replace that already existing code uses to process input.

So, is it possible to pad an input using a regex pattern with a regex replace? Again, I have no access to the code, so I cannot apply solution such as this [Pad left with zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901395/pad-left-with-zeroes)

What I can do is define a search pattern and a replace pattern that already existing code is using.

Here is what I am looking for:

```
INPUT       OUTPUT
1           000000001
12          000000012
123         000000123
12345678    012345678
123456789   123456789
```

Currently what I have for pattern is:

```
([0-9]{1,9})
```

and for replace:

```
000000000$1
```

But it doesn't do the job I need, it adds a fixed number of zeroes in front of the input, not a variable number. I suspect the task is impossible, given the restrictions I am working under, but I thought id ask anyway.

PS: the language of the code that reads regex is .NET (C#)

**EDIT 1:** Just to reiterate, I cannot change/alter code in any way, I cannot even see it. I assume this is what the existing code does:

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

`pattern` and `replacement` are strings being read from a configuration file, and I can change the values of those 2 strings. That's it. I cannot alter code reading it nor can I loop it to regex it twice or anything.

**EDIT 2:**
Not exactly what I'm looking for but (VB.NET code):

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, Function(match As Match)
                                                         Dim v As String = match.ToString()
                                                         Return String.Format("{0:000000000}", Val(v))
                                                     End Function)
```

Problem is, the `Function` is code, but if I stick that into property it will be read as a string and will not execute as code but as a replacement string. If I could only figure out how to make that string be treated as code, that would solve my issue.

**EDIT 3:** 
optimized code from EDIT 2(this time in C#):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, (v) => string.Format("{0:000000000}", double.Parse(v.Value)));
```

Still cannot figure out how to execute this piece of code `(v) => string.Format("{0:000000000}", double.Parse(v.Value))` without changing code on the server (which I have no access to), because it is stored as string. It feels like impossible to do without access to change code on the server.

**EDIT 4:**
Got a look at the server code that executes the regex:

```
searchVal = Regex.Replace(accountNumber, pattern, replace);
```

The "cannot change code" restriction still applies, so my suggestion from previous edit remains unreachable because it is treated as string and not code. I think this is an impossible task, given the restrictions i am working under.

Thank you all who tried to help

Comment: I think you're going to be stuck doing 8 different regex replaces... `\b\d\b` replace with `00000000$1`; `\b\d{2}\b` replace with `0000000$1`, etc.

Comment: Simplest would be to provide eight alternatives, counting is not sth. regular expressions are very good at.

Comment: Just to confirm: you want to only handle strings that consist of 1 to 9 digits and that start with a non-zero digit?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - the input can be a number with minimum length of 1 and maximum length of 9 and it can be any digit 0 to 9, but it cannot start with 0

Comment: Are you able to append something to input string?

Comment: @ctwheels - you might be on to something, however \b\d\b does not work for me. I'm trying now to figure out a formula where i replace 1 character with 00000000$1, 2 cahracters with 0000000$2 and so on. Just have to figure out how to do all that with a single pattern/replace combo

Comment: @revo - no, I have no access to the code that does the regex replace. I can only manipulate the properties that that code uses :(

Comment: So no string concatenation at all?

Comment: @revo - only through regex replace, which the current code executes if I tell it to in the second property. In my original post the regex replace property is `000000000$1` which means it will concatenate nine zeroes in front of the first match. I cannot write code that will concatenate, solution would be extremely easy if that was the case.

Comment: If you can run 2 consequent replacementrs, ctwheels' and another solution are possible.

Comment: If you can run 1 regex, then you can run 8 I guess. So, 8 find/replaces is all you need. 1. find `^(\d)$` replace `00000000$1` all the way to 8. find `^(\d{8})$` replace `0$1`. . . .  et all.

Comment: @sln, Wiktor Stribiżew - I cannot run regex more times that it already runs - I have no access to the code. Regex code only runs once. I updated my question to try and clear this up a bit more.

Comment: Hi Geroge, your question and limitations terribly remind me of my situation. If you don't mind, what is appliance or platform that you use? Maybe I can help if it's the same as mine, e.g. F5, Broadcom, SSG, CA, Cisco ? I usually limit my questions to sole regex101.com (no programming language allowed) and them port them to whever it's needed

Comment: @Peter LOL, its been over 2 years since I asked the question. I don't even remember which project I was working on that prompted that question. Regardless, we are a Microsoft shop and work in .NET environment (VB.NET/C#, but back then could of been any other older MS technology like VB6, ASP, etc)

Answer (score 4):

As you said, `.PadLeft()` really is the way to go about this, but you mention that you can't use it. Unfortunately, C# doesn't support conditional replacements for regex. I think the easiest option for you would be to create 8 different regular expressions as such:

```
\b([1-9])\b            00000000$1
\b([1-9]\d)\b          0000000$1
\b([1-9]\d{2})\b       000000$1
\b([1-9]\d{3})\b       00000$1
\b([1-9]\d{4})\b       0000$1
\b([1-9]\d{5})\b       000$1
\b([1-9]\d{6})\b       00$1
\b([1-9]\d{7})\b       0$1
```

---

Alternatively, doing all of this in one regex *is possible*, but you'd need to append a *dictionary* to the input as the following suggests:

[See it in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b1-9%5d%28%3f%3d.*1%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%28%3f%3d.*2%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b2%7d%28%3f%3d.*3%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b3%7d%28%3f%3d.*4%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b4%7d%28%3f%3d.*5%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b5%7d%28%3f%3d.*6%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b6%7d%28%3f%3d.*7%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%7c%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b7%7d%28%3f%3d.*8%5ct%2b%28%3f%3cx%3e0%2b%29%29%29%5cb&i=1%0d%0a12%0d%0a123%0d%0a12345678%0d%0a123456789%0d%0a%0d%0a1%0900000000%0d%0a2%090000000%0d%0a3%09000000%0d%0a4%0900000%0d%0a5%090000%0d%0a6%09000%0d%0a7%0900%0d%0a8%090&r=%24%7bx%7d%241&o=sm)

```
^([1-9](?=.*1\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d(?=.*2\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{2}(?=.*3\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{3}(?=.*4\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{4}(?=.*5\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{5}(?=.*6\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{6}(?=.*7\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{7}(?=.*8\t+(?<x>0+)))\b
```

Appending the following (note that SO shows spaces, but the numbers are separated by tabs):

```
1   00000000
2   0000000
3   000000
4   00000
5   0000
6   000
7   00
8   0
```

Replacement: `${x}$1`

How to add the dictionary? Well, if you have the ability to append it to the input that's the easiest option. Otherwise, using regex you can use `\z` [as seen here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cz&i=1&r=%5Cn1%5Ct00000000%5Cn2%5Ct0000000%5Cn3%5Ct000000%5Cn4%5Ct00000%5Cn5%5Ct0000%5Cn6%5Ct000%5Cn7%5Ct00%5Cn8%5Ct0&o=m). You'd then have to run the regex above to use the dictionary.

Replacement: `\n1\t00000000\n2\t0000000\n3\t000000\n4\t00000\n5\t0000\n6\t000\n7\t00\n8\t0`

---

If you're unable to run multiple regular expressions on a single input, I'm afraid what you're trying to accomplish cannot be done as each method requires at least 2 runs over the input to give you the expected output.

Comment: I did not downvote. That being said, how do I append a dictionary to the input?

Comment: @George well, you either simply append to the input if you have access or, if you don’t, you can do a regex replace using the position of the end of the input using `\z` to add it

Comment: I don't have access to the code at all. The code is on the server, I can only change the regex pattern and regex replace properties that the server reads. How does using `\z` work?

Comment: @George please see my edit, which includes `\z` usage

Comment: I am not sure I understand the procedure. Do I need to change code in order to do what you are asking? Because I cannot. I updated my question with some details to clear this up.

Comment: @George I'm not sure how the workflow is exactly, but if you can run one regex to edit the string (add the dictionary) and a second to add the zeros, then you can use the second approach. Otherwise, you're stuck running multiple regular expressions. C# doesn't have the ability to do a conditional replace. The dictionary method is a regex hack to do *conditional replacements* in a weird way.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question no matter how many solutions with different unavailable prerequisites you add to it.

Comment: @revo the proposed solutions may work for the user. It really depends on how the code-behind is setup. Unfortunately, the OP doesn't even know how that's setup, so the only thing they can do is test the methods I propose to see if, indeed, one of them works. If neither works, they're, unfortunately, SOL.

Comment: "may" even doesn't apply here. OP quiet clearly said what he has in hands and in what restrictions he is. These solutions don't follow his rules. So simply not an answer to the question.

Comment: @revo the OP would not have known they can't loop twice over the input had they not tried something to alter the input twice, thus this may have led them to the solution that it's not actually possible with their restrictions. The edit was added after my solution was posted.

Comment: Not OP's fault but your understanding. You didn't ask for any further clarifications either. I asked and got replies just before you answered. If you have questions which will affect your answers you should ask early.

Comment: @revo Just to clarify, I'm not blaming the OP. Suggesting what is written in my answer using a comment would have been ludicrous, so I found posting an answer might lead them to some hacky method of using dictionaries or multiple regexes to solve their issue and, if not, it would not be possible.

Comment: Whatever happened before, not an answer right now. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @revo Agreed. There is, unfortunately, no solution for this. I edited my answer a little while ago to include that information.

Comment: I updated my question with the piece of server code. In short, there is no loop to execute regex twice.

Comment: @ctwheels - that is mind-bending! 
I Finally worked out the 
"(?=.*1\t(?<x>0+)\b)" 
is basically a match then a concatenation of the 0's' stored in <x> from the search of the digits after the 'dictionary' '1'  lookup. Super slick!

Answer (score 0):

You could not use regex but the built in C# `$""` to generate the string. For example `$"{userInput:D9}"` will pad the number to be nine digits long.

Comment: You've missed a crucial part of the problem - no code change. Your approach requires code change. This problem has been posted so long ago I don't even remember it no more LOL