# How to pad zeroes into String using regex - using only regex101.com

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to come up with "Regular expression" and a "Substitute" to pad any string that's shorter than 10 characters with zeros. It has to work on regex101.com, PHP flavor. This is all I need.

```
Example Input:

123
12345
1234567891

Expected output:

0000000123
0000012345
1234567891
```

I wish it was simple as searching for ([0-9]{1,9}) and replacing it with 000000000$1 but obviously string would exceed length of 10 characters. So I am trying with read ahead syntax but no luck.

Comment: That does not sound feasible. You need a conditional replacement pattern which is supported by PCRE2 (and Boost, e.g.).

Comment: That functionality doesn't exist for regex101. You'll have to use a coding language. Alternatively, if you're looking for a "quick hack" using an online IDE, you can jump onto tio.run and create something like [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJVHBViHa0MhYB4hNTCGkmbmFpWGsNVdafpGGSqatgbVKpk1yfmleiYZKoiaQo62tqVDNxamSGK2SGQvUX1xSFF@QmKIBEdAxNNBRN1DXCQ4Jig9wdIn3cXUL0bTmquUqSyyKTynNLQCb8v8/AA).

Comment: Hi ctwheels, I have been reading your posts all day actually, it seems you have been around indntical topic a lot. I have seen your post where you append the catalog. Sadly I am not allowed to add anything on the given input. Your reply was this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891333/pad-number-with-variable-length-zeroes-using-regex

Comment: however I am allowed to run as many transformations as I wish, each time output becomes input for new iteration. But I don't see how this can help.

Comment: Logic as length goes is not the realm of regular expressions. That is the first commandment. The second is that it cannot parse language. Third is even though hear `word` it is just a metaphor for a character class. So regex is not suited for this. You could find and replace with a callback logic, but you could also use format()

Comment: If you can run as many as you need, why don't you just run them? 1) `^\d$` => `000000000$0`, 2) `^\d{2}$` => `00000000$0`, 3) `^\d{3}$` => `0000000$0`, 4) `^\d{4}$` => `000000$0`, 5) `^\d{5}$` => `00000$0`, 6) `^\d{6}$` => `0000$0`, 7) `^\d{7}$` => `000$0`, 8) `^\d{8}$` => `00$0`, 9) `^\d{9}$` => `0$0`

Comment: Thanks to all 3 replies, I am getting somewhere. If I sucseed, I'll post reply, but maybe someone more experienced should give the final conclusion., This is unbeliveably frequent question in world of security appliances. Thanks for comments. Very helpful !

Comment: Do you have all of the string values, or are you using regex to capture text *inside* of a page/string?

Comment: Hi Joel, It's clean number, nothing else, no html or anything. Usecase is : 7 or 8 or 9 numbers which needs to become prefxed with 0.

Comment: If you know they all just strings, why not just use `.` to add 10 zeroes to each string, then `split` them from `str.length-10` to get the last 4 digits? `"0000000000".str` then `newStr.split(str, str.length-10)`?

Comment: Joel - where in regex101.do you put java ? Same remark to Edward. Please stick to the topic.

Comment: Its widely known that regex engine writers provide 1 or 2 regex replacement function prototypes in C++ that are compiled and imported as a dll or included directly in C++ apps. These primitive functions only allow replacement string input pointer/object or  function callback pointer (optional  instead of replacement) that recieves the match object, formats a replacement then returns it to the replacement caller. The default behavior when just a string is passed is to parse it for group number notation like `$1` , `\1`, `${1}` and do that substitution. Does this answer your question on topic ?

Comment: try `format("%010d",atoi(str));`

Comment: Peter - It's a valid question.

Comment: Joel, Edward - When I put this as regular expression: format("%010d",atoi(str)) - it generates error. Can either of you share link to example regex101.com where it works for you ?

Comment: Thanks to Wiktor and  ctwheels. Both answers actually work well.  ctwheels regex gives answer in one step, but requires catalog to be appended. Wiktor's solution to run regex 9 times actually works. I didn't expect to get 2 answers on this complex topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments below your question, I provided a .NET method using a catalog to pad a string in regex without using a conditional replacement ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48891673/3600709)).

This answer can be adapted to PCRE by using a branch reset group `(?|...)`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/qjalQw/1)

Options `gJsm` and substitution of `${x}$1`

```
^((?|[1-9](?=.*1\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d(?=.*2\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{2}(?=.*3\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{3}(?=.*4\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{4}(?=.*5\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{5}(?=.*6\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{6}(?=.*7\t+(?<x>0+))|[1-9]\d{7}(?=.*8\t+(?<x>0+))))\b
```

The result:

```
1
12
123
12345678
123456789
```

Becomes...

```
000000001
000000012
000000123
012345678
123456789
```

Comment: This regex doesn't work with PCRE. When I modify it to:
^([1-9](?=.*1\t+(?<a>0+))|[1-9]\d(?=.*2\t+(?<b>0+))|[1-9]\d{2}(?=.*3\t+(?<c>0+))|[1-9]\d{3}(?=.*4\t+(?<d>0+))|[1-9]\d{4}(?=.*5\t+(?<e>0+))|[1-9]\d{5}(?=.*6\t+(?<f>0+))|[1-9]\d{6}(?=.*7\t+(?<g>0+))|[1-9]\d{7}(?=.*8\t+(?<h>0+))|[1-9]\d{8}(?=.*9\t+(?<i>0+))|[1-9]\d{9}(?=.*10\t+(?<j>0+)))\b
and replacement string: ${a}${b}${c}${d}${e}${f}${g}${h}${i}${j}$1
then it works fine. However catalog is needed, and that's a killer, i ca't modify input.

Comment: It’s not possible with regex alone without appending a catalog. That’s the only way to do it in PCRE without using code