# Regex to match variants of a string and left pad with zeros

Tags: regex

Assume I have running system I can parameterize with a regex and a replacement string to check some strings and left pad a part of it matching the regex with zero.

Internally the system used standard Java features for regex and IS NOT SUBJECT TO CHANGE (no usage of other methods or classes):

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Main
{ // args[0]= "sample 066666 33 more text" -- will be read from database and is neither subject to change
  // args[1]= "(\\d{0,9}\\d)([ _-])([3-9][0-9])" 
  // args[2]= "$1-$3"
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (args[1]);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher (args[0]);
    if (matcher.find ())
      {
System.out.println (matcher.replaceFirst (args[2]));
    // prints 'sample 066666-33 more text'
    // but should be 'sample 0000066666-33 more text'
      }

  }
}
```

It is just about how to define regex and replacement string passed to main() in order to
a) left pad the matching part with zeros up to 10 digits and
b) to replace different delimiters such as space or _ by default delimiter -

(Context: it is not my application, so I cannot change the code, just provide a configuration by those two arguments [1] and [2] for this specific use case here. In other cases the input as well as the regex might be completely different to receive completely different results. It is like parameterizing a generic component with specific regex for a specific use case/ outcome)

Samples for arg[0]:

```
abc 1-31 def
abc 02 31 def
abc 55555_32 def
abc 066666 33 def
this value 1010101010-34 is what it should be like
```

should result in

```
abc 0000000001-31 def
abc 0000000002-32 def
abc 0000055555-32 def
abc 0000066666-33 def
this value 1010101010-34 is what it should be like
```

I managed to match them by

```
(\d{0,9}\d)([ _-])([3-9][0-9])
```

, but I could not find a way to left pad with zeros to exact 10 digits before the delimiter, while there might be correct left padded numbers contained in a string or due to manual input leading zeros but not filled up to 10 numbers.

I found a solution using dictionary but did not really manage to use as I cannot extend the input (args[0]) but hopefully add the dictionary to the regex?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48891673/16110438

I've seen other solutions such as having multiple capture groups

```
(\d{9})|...|(\d{2})|(\d)
```

with replacement such as

```
(?{1}$1)(?{2}$2)(?{3}$3)
```

but again it did not work with padding and I did not quite understand what '?{1}' really stands for.

Do you have any suggestion for me, is that possible at within a single regex execution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you match all numbers before the `-` and replace the zeros? You wouldn't need RegEx for this.

Comment: @Tom - You forgot to mention that you also want to replace other separators by `-`, didn't you?

Comment: _regex and replacement string will be provided by a http call and passed to_ **which** _Java function_?

Comment: Hi at all, updated the description regarding your questions. Looking forward to your suggestions. 
@Coli with the new samples given I think your approach won't work, do you have another idea?

Comment: Have you tried `String.format`?

Comment: Hi everyone contributing here. I just updated the question: I am looking for a **pure regex** solution only, and not for answers to change the Java code cause I cannot change it (I'm even not a developer having access to the code) and this is not the question here from my side. So if anyone has a regex solution I can use to configure our system from the outside, this being passed to the Java code as is, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Your shown code doesn't compile.  You should edit your post to show a [mre].

Comment: Provided working code example, still it is not about changing the java code but providing a regex as parameter only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] arr = {
                "1-31",
                "02#31",
                "55555-32",
                "066666/33",
                "999999999 34",
                "1010101010-35"
        };
        
        for(String s: arr) {
            String formatted = String.format("%13s", s.replaceAll("[#/\\s]", "-")).replace(' ', '0');
            System.out.println(formatted);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0000000001-31
0000000002-31
0000055555-32
0000066666-33
0999999999-34
1010101010-35
```

Comment: Hi everyone contributing here. I just updated the question: I am looking for a **pure regex** solution only, and not for answers to change the Java code cause I cannot change it (I'm even not a developer having access to the code) and this is not the question here from my side. So if anyone has a regex solution I can use to configure our system from the outside, this being passed to the Java code as is, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Any solution given that is different than yours would be changing the code.  You need to be more specific as to what may or may not change.

Comment: @WJS updated description, I hope it makes it much clearer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Used Regex:

```
"(\\d{10})\\D+(\\d+)"
```

Regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1-31\n"
            + "02#31\n"
            + "55555-32\n"
            + "066666/33\n"
            + "999999999 34\n"
            + "1010101010-35";

    String paddedInput = Pattern.compile("^", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input).replaceAll("0".repeat(9));
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{10})\\D+(\\d+)", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(paddedInput);
    while(matcher.find()) { // adjusting the padding and numbers in group 1 to a total of 10 digits
        System.out.printf("%s-%s%n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0000000001-31
0000000002-31
0000055555-32
0000066666-33
0999999999-34
1010101010-35
```