# c# Fill string with 0 at left

Tags: c#, string, format

I try to fill a string with 0 at left.

My variable :

```
string value = "0.5";
```

So my output is `0.5` and I want `00.5`. This value can also be an integer like `450`, needed as `0450`.

I tried  `string.Format("{0:0000}", value);` but it doesn't work.

I also tried `string value = (double.Parse(value)).ToString("0000");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `PadLeft`?

Comment: What's wrong with `string value = $"0{value}";`?

Comment: And yes, if it is to a fixed length, `PadLeft` is the way to go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Please see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros

Comment: Thanks guys, it's solved !

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901395/pad-left-with-zeroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`PadLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_) method for that

```cs
var value = "0.5";
var result = value.PadLeft(4, '0'); //gives 00.5
```