# C#: Pad number with 0 from the left until length is X characters?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a number with 0's, until its 3 or more characters. I've done a not-so-dynamic approach below, but I was wondering if C# had anything built in?

For example, "77" would become "077", "6" would become "006", and "63" would become "063"

Is there a built in / better way?

```
            _totalSupplierCount = GetTotalSupplierNumberForInvoices().ToString().Left<double>(3);

            _totalSupplierCountStr = _totalSupplierCount.ToString();

            if (_totalSupplierCountStr.Length == 2)
            {
                _totalSupplierCountStr = "0" + _totalSupplierCountStr;
            }

            if (_totalSupplierCountStr.Length == 1)
            {
                _totalSupplierCountStr = "000" + _totalSupplierCountStr;
            }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901395/pad-left-with-zeroes

Comment: `string result = source.PadLeft(3, '0');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pad left with zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901395/pad-left-with-zeroes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c

Comment: Or the simple `GetTotalSupplierNumberForInvoices().ToString("000")`

Comment: `string val = num.ToString("000");`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the page on [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), particularly the ["D" specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#decimal-format-specifier-d).

> The precision specifier indicates the minimum number of digits desired in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision specifier.

This means you can alter your `ToString()` call to use the format "D3", which will pad up to 3 digits with 0's as necessary:

```
int totalSupplierCount = 3;
string totalSupplierCountStr = totalSupplierCount.ToString("D3");
```

You might prefer to use the slightly shorter:

```
string totalSupplierCountStr = $"{totalSupplierCount:D3}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better method. You could *repeat* `0` character by `3 - your_string_length` times.

For avoiding any *error / exception* you could use an *if* condition.

```
if(_totalSupplierCountStr.Length < 3) {
    _totalSupplierCountStr = new String('0', 3 - _totalSupplierCountStr.Length) + _totalSupplierCountStr;
}
```

Another approach could be using `PadLeft` method.

```
_totalSupplierCountStr = _totalSupplierCountStr.PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Comment: If you're taking the string manipulation approach why not use [`PadLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0) (as given in the comments on the question), rather than rolling your own version?

Comment: @canton7, I specified in my answer the approach you're mentioning. Thanks for your point!